# Unable to parse a date Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

```
var date = "05/18/2012";

DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

DateTime.Parse(date);
```

I think the problem here is that the date should be day/month/year. The problem is that the client wants it in this format. The system must be able to operate in English and french. I want all dates to be parsed in the same way so they are all in the format - yyyy/MM/dd.

Neither of the previous examples seem to work.

EDIT: I can set the date in the format 2012/05/18 but how do I do that for a DateTime.Now?

Comment: your var date should be "2012/05/18" according to the format you specified. Are you trying to get it format the date in the format you provided?

Comment: One problem is your ParseExact format isn't even close to the form you claim the date it should be in.  You have a value formated with the month, day, and then year and try to parse it in some entirely different format.  I hope you are not trying to store the format itself instead of the value ( which has no format ).

Comment: FYI thanks for the downvotes. It really enriches the community...

Comment: @JonathanO:  My downvote was because this question makes little sense -- it states "parsing" (input) but question _appears_ (not clear) to be about output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ParseExact allows you to tell the parser what format the date is in. So in your example you are saying it is yyyy/MM/dd so you should have the date setup like "2012/05/18" for it to parse correctly.

Here is example.

```
var date = "05/18/2012";
var date2 = "2012/05/18";

var pDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
var pDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date2, "yyyy/MM/dd", null);

Console.WriteLine("Normal Date Formated: " + pDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
Console.WriteLine("Your Format, Parsed: " + pDate2.ToShortDateString());
Console.WriteLine("DateTime.Now Formatted: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Output

```
Normal Date Formated: 2012/05/18
Your Format, Parsed: 5/18/2012
DateTime.Now Formatted: 2012/09/18
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
string date = "05/18/2012";
DateTime dateA = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newDate = dateA.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I know this will work but I need it in the format yyyy/mm/dd. It is a project req

Comment: @JonathanO how about converting it back to string `string newDate = dateA.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`?